# Changes in the body of the program are not being saved when ActiveWorkbook.Close happens

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA program that opens a .txt file and does some search for certain row/columns highlights those row/columns and then does a ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs.  The problem I'm having is the changes don't get saved when I follow up with an "ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True"  Thanks in advance Scott

```
Option Explicit

Sub Import_txt()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim x As Long
    Dim y As Long
    Dim z As Long

' Import_txt Macro
'
'
    ChDir "C:\Users\parsons_s\Desktop\Verity II\G5_KLARF"
    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:= _
        "C:\Users\parsons_s\Desktop\Verity II\G5_KLARF\G5_KLARF.txt", Origin:=437, _
        StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
        ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, _
        Space:=True, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3 _
        , 1), Array(4, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True


      'Find_txt Macro
    Cells.Find(What:="SampleTestPlan", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas _
        , LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

        x = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1)
        y = ActiveCell.Row + 1
        z = ActiveCell.Row + 16
        i = 0


       With ActiveSheet
       'Shade Field Actions Blue
        Do While i < x
        Cells(y + i, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
        Cells(y + i, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
        i = i + 1
        Loop
        Cells(z, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
        Cells(z, 4).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
        End With


    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\parsons_s\Desktop\Verity II\G5_KLARF\G5_KLARF_Find_locations.xls"


    'ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True

    Windows("KLARF converter.xlsm").Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Sam, for some reason VBA editor will not let me capitalize "Filename".  Do you think that's my problem?

Comment: What you are doing is playing with the text file, changing colors on the cells and saving it - which I dont think may work. What you can do is copy the text file to the destination excel file and change the `ColorIndex` on it. The newly created excel file can have formatting preserved. Effectively, the text file wont have the formatting saved with it.

Comment: Thanks Shahkalpesh, you're right the Active file remains a .txt and even though I "SaveAs" a .xls. Should I do the copy right after the import?

Comment: Yes. After `Workbooks.OpenText`, you can do a `SaveAs` to a new file and work on new xls(x) file for rest of the code.

Comment: Found it! You need to add the FileFormat:= after the SaveAs.  'Convert file form .txt to .xls
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:="C:\Users\parsons_s\Desktop\Verity II\G5_KLARF\G5_KLARF_Find_locations.xls", _
        FileFormat:=xlExcel12

Comment: Thanks to all the good support here and thanks to stackoverflow!